# Three.js JSON (blender export) animations

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I can't seem to get this model to animate in three.js.
I've tried exporting it so many different ways, but I'm not sure if it's the model or the code. I'm getting a trace on the animations from the model, but nothing happens on the call-back. Any ideas?

```
new THREE.JSONLoader().load( 'assets/model/Gunnar.json', function ( model, material ) {

var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(model, material);
scene.add( mesh );

mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 5;

var clips = model.animations;
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
mixer.clipAction( clips[0] ).play();

loaded = true;
animate();

} );


function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

if (loaded) {
  mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
}

renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Blender/JSON files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxy6q3wjydmtlhd/json_blender_files.zip?dl=0

[image: blender export settings]

[image]